# Remove emboss style on a disabled TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, tabitem

I've got the following `TabItem` (by saying "TabItem", I actually mean the button to activate the Tab):

```
<TabItem RequestBringIntoView="activateTab_Click" Name="tabImplantation" Width="270" Height="138" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" IsEnabled="False" Foreground="#FF075C81">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="148"  Margin="-5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="implantation_pic" Source="/project;component/Images/implantation_a.jpg" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    ...
</TabItem>
```

As you see, it's a customized `TabItem` with an `Image` object in it. I've removed the border by setting `BorderBrush="{x:Null}"` and it works well.

However, if it's disabled (`IsEnabled="False"`), it renders some kind of an inner emboss shadow or something like that (could also be a border, I'm not sure about that).

How to render it without this border in case it's disabled? See also the pictures below. Thanks in advance!

Please note that I'm not a c# expert and I'm just doing some restyling. The development of the program itself was outsourced.

[image: The TabItem is enabled and renders correctly]

[image: The TabItem is disabled and renders a border]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the look you want you'll have to edit the `TabItem`'s [`ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (this is easy to do using Blend).

There's no "inner emboss shadow" that's being rendered when the control's disabled, it maybe the border effect. Here's the edited version of the `ControlTemplate` that disables that border when `IsEnabled = false` (Add this to your `Window.Resources` or `Application.Resources`) :

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="3,3,3,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabControlNormalBorderBrush" Color="#8C8E94"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#EAF6FD" Offset="0.15"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#D9F0FC" Offset=".5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#BEE6FD" Offset=".5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#A7D9F5" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemSelectedBackground" Color="#F9F9F9"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBorderBrush" Color="#3C7FB1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBackground" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBorderBrush" Color="#FFC9C7BA"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TabItemFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <!--previous (default) border brush value was BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"-->
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHotBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemSelectedBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHotBorderBrush}"/>

                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-1,-2,-2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-1,-2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-2,-2,-2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <!--previous (default) border brush value was BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBorderBrush}"-->
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBackground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Here's how the control will look like after applying the style changes (Preview in Blend + SketchFlow for VS2012) :

[image: Preview in Blend + SketchFlow for VS2012]